# Exception handling, first try/catch blocks don't reiterate until proper input is accepted

Tags: java, exception

Writing a program that asks user's input to calculate whether they can afford a car or not. when prompting the user to enter the price of the car, my try/catch blocks do not work as desired. the program continues to run the code after the first try/catch block. worth noting that all the other code works as desired (the program asks for a lot of doubles to be entered, only the first one doesn't work)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Minimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Car car = new Car();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter("number.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("What is the msrp?");

        try 
        {
            double price = sc.nextDouble();
            car.setStickerPrice(price);
            out.println(price);
        }   
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("The MSRP is a numberical value, please reenter a number.");
            out.println("The MSRP is a numberical value, please reenter a number.");
        }
        System.out.println("What is your down payment?");
        out.println("What is your down payment?");





        double pay = 0;
        while (true) {

            try {
                pay = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
                break; // will only get to here if input was a double
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                 System.out.println("Invalid input, input a numerical value: ");  
            }
        }



        car.setDownPayment(pay);
        out.println(pay);
        car.setOutTheDoor();
        System.out.println(
                "Please enter your interest rate (APR) as a decimal value. For example, an interest rate of 3% would be entered as '.03.'");
        out.println(
                "Please enter your interest rate (APR) as a decimal value. For example, an interest rate of 3% would be entered as '.03.'");




        double rate = 0;
        while (true) {

            try {
                rate = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
                break; // will only get to here if input was a double
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                 System.out.println("Invalid input, input a numerical value: ");  
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

What is the msrp?
g
The MSRP is a numberical value, please reenter a number.
What is your down payment?
Invalid input, input a numerical value:
g
Invalid input, input a numerical value:
g
Invalid input, input a numerical value:
1
Please enter your interest rate (APR) as a decimal value. For example, an interest rate of 3% would be entered as '.03.'
g
Invalid input, input a numerical value:
g
Invalid input, input a numerical value:
5

Answer (score 0):

That's not how try/catch blocks work. If you need that behavior then you need to put the try/catch in a loop.

```
while(true) {
    try { ask question; break; }
    catch { error handling }
}
```

You'll only hit the "break" if the question doesn't throw an exception.

Slightly different version of the same thing that might be easier to understand...

```
bool inputValid = false;
while(!inputValid){
    try { ask question; inputValid = true; }
    catch { error handling }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that and it just keeps looping indefinitely how can I fix that?

Comment: It will only loop forever if it never gets valid inut. Have you tried printing the input to make sure it gets what you expect?